# Java: Extract characters after a specific character

Tags: java, string

I have urls in strings like below

```
http://www.example.com/abc?page=6
http://www.example.com/abc?page=66
http://www.example.com/abc?page=666
```

I want to extract only the page numbers i.e only the characters after "=" using string functions in java but do not know how to do this. Please help

Thank you

Comment: Regular expressions are a good way of solving this kind of problem. It's well worth investing some time in learning them, since you can apply them in a wide range of programming languages

Comment: It may be sloppy (don't use regexs much) but this will be a good matching group in case there are multiple parameters. `([a-zA-Z]+=[0-9]+)`

Comment: @Legend maybe he wants only digits then `([0-9]+)` will be suitable.

Comment: I guess I just had a different thought process. The answer I provided would be suitable for inputting the data into a map.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When the case is as simple as just getting anything after a given character, you don't really need regular expressions.

**Example**

```
String test = "http://www.example.com/abc?page=6";
String number = test.substring(test.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
System.out.println(number);
```

**Output**

```
6
```

**Note**

If your `String` does not contain the `=` character, the result will be the whole `String`.

That'll happen because method `lastIndexOf` will return `- 1`, which is summed with `+1` in the example, hence returning `0`.

In short, it would return a sub-string of your whole `String` starting at `0` and extending to the whole length of the original `String`.

Comment: @LalithMohan you're welcome. A detail: if your String does **not** contain the "=" character, the result will be the whole String. That'll happen because method "lastIndexOf" will return - 1, which is summed with +1, hence 0. In short, it would return a substring of your whole String starting at 0 and extending to the whole length of the original String.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `String.substring method`

```
   String result = input.substring(input.indexOf("=")+1);
```

**Additional info**

as per java doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)

> ```
> public String substring(int beginIndex)
> ```
>
> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the
>   end of this string.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that you can use to extract the integer value of any given parameter inside an URL ( not only "page") is:

```
public static int extractIntFromURL(String url,String par) throws ParameterNotFoundInURLException{
    int number=0;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[?&]"+par+"=([0-9]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
    m.find();
    try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    } catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException e){
        throw new ParameterNotFoundInURLException(url);
    }

    return number;
}
```

If the URL doesn't containg "page=" if throws an exception, as returning zero would be wrong, as zero can be a valid page number.

You can use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParameterNotFoundInURLException {
    String url="http://www.example.com/abc?page=66&other=yes&filter=none";
    int pageNum = TheClass.extractIntFromURL(url,"page");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format of your URLs is fixed

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/abc?page=666";
String page = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=')+1);
System.out.println(page); // prints 666
```

If there could be other request parameters later on

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/book?id=101&page=60&bookmarks=on";
String page = url.split("\\?")[1].replaceAll(".*page=([^&]+).*", "$1");
System.out.println(page); // prints 60
```